# PHP File Uploads - .htaccess allowed file types

Tags: php, image, .htaccess

I have a site that allows users to upload images - png, jpg, jpeg, gif. I've been told to include the following code in the .htaccess file in the root of the site (eg: allows to everything regarding the site). Is this the best way to go about this?

```
deny from all
<Files ~ "^\w+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
order deny,allow
allow from all
</Files>
```

Basically I want to add a touch of extra protection to file types being uploaded. I know its not fool proof but just a touch more protection... thoughts?

thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check when a file is an image with GD's function [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) or [getimagesizefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php). Then for every file being uploaded you check dimension. If the function you are using returns `false` then the file isn't an image.

With `getimagesize` you can also check the mime-type, so you can limit an image to be a specific type.